# Using cloudformation condition to create Root volume if development enviornment is choosen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a root volume is production env. is chosen from parameters, which works fine, but if dev is chosen, it throws an error. "Value of property BlockDeviceMappings must be of type List"

```html
Parameters:
  Enviornment:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter the enviornment where you want the instance deployed
    AllowedValues:
      - Production
      - Development
Conditions: 
  isProduction: !Equals [!Ref Enviornment, Production]
Resources:
  Ec2Instace:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref AvailabilityZone
      ImageId: !Ref AmiId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref Ec2KeyPair
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt SecurityGp.GroupId
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        !If
            - isProduction
            -
              - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
                Ebs:
                      VolumeType: gp2 
                      VolumeSize: 21
            - !Ref Enviornment
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing the Production scenario to work but development to throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!Ref Enviornment` is incorrect. I guess you want to have the following:

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instace:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref AvailabilityZone
      ImageId: !Ref AmiId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref Ec2KeyPair
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt SecurityGp.GroupId
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        !If
            - isProduction
            -
              - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
                Ebs:
                      VolumeType: gp2 
                      VolumeSize: 21
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```